# Chrome Customs Tabs

Tags: android, animation, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using the chrome custom tabs in my news app. i want the custom enter and exit animations, but when I use the code :

```
builder.setStartAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
builder.setExitAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Android is not recognizing the layout files.

Comment: you're missing the android package: `android.R.anim.slide_in_left`

Comment: This works in only builder.setExitAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

Answer (score 0):

> slide_in_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

> slide_out_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

You can use above transitions as a `StartAnimation` while for `ExitAnimation` you can use default android animations that is,

```
builder.setExitAnimations(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```